# How do I render/animate out items that leave array

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I have a **scraper** that scrapes slack messages and stores them in a db somewhere.

On the frontend, I am pulling every second to see if new messages pop up. And then I render those messages on screen.

If anyone on slack replies or emotes on a message, the message gets removed from the backend thus getting removed from the frontend.

What I am trying to do now is when an item gets removed, I would like to animate it somehow.

Here is some of my current code:

```
async componentDidMount() {

        await this.grab_channels()
        await this.grab_slack_user_data()
        await this.grab_items()

        setInterval(() => {
            this.grab_items()
        }, this.state.settings.seconds_per_slack_messages_pull * 1000 )
    }
```

```
grab_items() {

        let url = this.state.settings.api_url + 'channel/' + this.state.selected_channel + '/now'

        return new Promise( resolve => {
            axios.get( url )
                .then( res => {
                    this.setState( { items: res.data } )
                    resolve()
                } )
        })

    }
```

And finally, items get rendered:

```
this.props.items.map( t => { 
                        return (
                            <Item 
                                key={ t.usr + '_' + t.ts } 
                                task={ t } 
                                user={ this.props.slack_users[ t.usr ] } 
                                settings={ this.props.settings } 
                                now={  this.state.now } 
                                /> 
                        )
                    } )
```

I was thinking of doing some sort of check within `grab_items()` but I wouldn't know how to continue after that. It would be easy to determine which ones should be rendered out but the problem is actually doing it.

Anyone have experience building something like this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Transition Groups is one way to do this:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Take a look at this example:
https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group

Comment: After doing a bit more research myself, I found transition groups and it is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the check part in your function grab_items

```
   /* include "clone" so that we don't modify state directly */
    import clone from 'clone'

      grab_items() {
        let url = this.state.settings.api_url + 'channel/' + this.state.selected_channel + '/now'

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          axios.get(url).then(res => {
            /* figure out what items to remove before you set the state */
            let itemsToShow = []
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
              let ifFound = false
              let t = clone(this.state.items[i])
              for (let j = 0; j < res.data.length; j++) {
                if (t.key === res.data[j].key) {
                  ifFound = true
                }
              }
              /* if ifFound is false, it means it is not in the messages any more. */
              if(!ifFound){
                t.haveAnimation = true
                itemsToShow.push(t)
              }
              itemsToShow = itemsToShow.concat(res.data)
              this.setState(itemsToShow)
            }
          })
        })
      }
```

Then every second when it re-pull the data, you will have a list of items to show. The list has the items need to have the "disappear" animation and also it has the new messages.

To make the animation work, in the render part:

```
  this.props.items.map(t => {
    return (
      <Item
        key={t.usr + '_' + t.ts}
        className={t.haveAnimation ? 'animationCSS' : ''}
        task={t}
        user={this.props.slack_users[t.usr]}
        settings={this.props.settings}
        now={this.state.now}
      />
    )
  }
```

Above code should attach the css class to the Item. You can put whatever css animation in the class